# Two divs floating left and right: How can I keep them on the same level when a page resizes?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, css-float

Given the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left" style="float: left; background-color: #777; width: 500px;">
      Here is some content. Blah blah blah etc.
      <div style="height: 50px;">Some more content</div>
      And finally some more.
    </div>
    <div id="right" style="float: right; background-color: #aaa; width: 500px;">
      Here is some content. Blah blah blah etc.
      <div style="height: 50px;">Some more content</div>
      And finally some more.
    </div>
    <div style="float: clear;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What can I do to `div#container` or another tag to prevent `div#right` from moving under `div#left` when I resize the browser window such that the windows width is smaller then `1000px`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set a `min-width` to your container:

```
#container {
  min-width: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Give the `#container` DIV a `min-width: 1000px` property, that way the parent will always be wide enough to hold both the children side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

Container div not closed in your code. please check it once, and apply min-width:1000px;

Answer (score -2):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp I learned all of my CSS here, there is a section on positioning that is quite helpful I suggest reading it for what your working on now as well as future projects.

Try:

```
#container {
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: That didn't do it. You should change your answer or remove the code. I appreciate the link though. I'll check it out.