# Prevent content of positioned:fixed; div from bunching when window is resized

Tags: css, html, position

I hope this is not a repost! I have looked everywhere and so I am sorry if it is.

I have a header div that is position:fixed and it has some image links and a login div. Since the position:fixed is relative to the window, whenever I resize the windows to test liquidity, the content in the header div gets jammed and starts to drop down the page.

Is there anyway to get a horizontal scroll bar to appear and remove the space? I have min-width set on the body and the header div but no luck. I am not coding for IE at the moment and only using latest Chrome and Firefox for testing now.

Thank you for any help!

CSS:

```
body {
min-width:1000px;
padding-top:0;
padding-bottom:0;
margin:0;
background-color:#022F00;
}

.container {
padding: 0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
height:100%;
margin-top:160px;
}

.header {
width:inherit;
padding:5px;
position:fixed;
left:20px;
right:20px;
top:15px;;
min-width:850px;
}

.login {
float:right;
padding:0;
margin:0;
border:0;
position:relative;
}
img {
margin:0;
border:0;
padding:0;
}

a {
margin:0;
border:0;
padding:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="header" id="titlebar"><img src="title.jpg" /><a href="createaccount.php"><img src="newaccount.jpg"></a><a href="addarticle.php"><img src="newarticle.jpg"></a><a href='myaccount.php' rel=''><img src="myaccount.jpg"></a>
    <div class="login" id="logindiv">content</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found this solution, it may help you

---

Set a min-width to your container:

```
#container { min-width: 1000px;}
```

you may want to check this link

[Two divs floating left and right: How can I keep them on the same level when a page resizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082894/two-divs-floating-left-and-right-how-can-i-keep-them-on-the-same-level-when-a-pa)

it was an answer to 
"Two divs floating left and right: How can I keep them on the same level when a page resizes? "[follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082894/two-divs-floating-left-and-right-how-can-i-keep-them-on-the-same-level-when-a-pa)

Comment: I have tried inline CSS to fix this problem, but I don't really understand how that makes a difference?

Comment: Thanks a lot of the help! That worked perfectly. I wish in the future they would it easier to keep things liquid without having to define a set width. Thanks again.